# MVVM Dispatcher UI not responisve

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

I ran in a probrably simple problem:

I build a MVVM application with MVVM light.

When I'm doing a big calculation my UI is not responsive.
I need a dispatcher because I want do access some Dependency Objects.

I tried to do with that code: (Might not work because I'm using the Application Thread?!)

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                //LongTimeStuff
            }));
```

I also tried:

```
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
        {
             //LongTimeStuff
        });
```

But here I get the problem, that my Dependency Objects are in another thread.

All those stuff I do within a function of a new Thread:

```
   Thread CalculationThread = new Thread(this.Calculate);
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you trued using async await?

Comment: where to set this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

First - I had do put out my "LongTimeStuff" out of the Dispatcher.

Second - I had do do: `Task.Sleep(1);` in my loop and suddenly it works.
To idea why but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatcher BeginInvoke or InvokeAsync does not run anything is separate thread. It only add task to Dispatcher queue of tasks. But the dispatcher queue is processed always on UI thread.

here's what should you do:

```
void CommandExecuted()
{
   Task.Run(() =>
   {
     //long running stuff

     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
     {
       //access ui here
     }));
}
```

or using async pattern:

```
    async void CommandExecuted()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //long running stuff
        });
        //access ui here
    }
```

Comment: I start my Thread this way - CalculationThread.Start(); - ist that a problem?!

Comment: No it's not, although tasks are recommended. The problem is the longrunning stuff inside Dispatcher.BeginInvoke as you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Run your longtime stuff in a new Thread/Task, whenever you need access to  Dependency Objects, then invoke to main thread, for example:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        Task.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            //LongTimeStuff
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                textBlock1.Text = "10";

            }));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, it should work, there maybe some other problems!

Comment: What could be the other problems?
My UI is always responsive - when I start this Thread it's not.

Comment: Are You sure that you put your LongTimeStuff out of ` Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` right? because it must be responsive when starting a new thread.

Comment: No I did not do that! ;)
But then i need for every single property a dispatcher?

Comment: whenever you need to invoke main thread then you need a dispatcher, in that you can access any Control you like, in normal situation, after processing longtime task, you only need dispatcher one time, and access all controls in it for displaying result

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the DisptatcherPriority and you don't need BeginInvoke if you are planning to start working on another thread before:

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                //LongTimeStuff
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
                {
                    textblock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                }));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your work in another thread, then use the dispatcher to update your UI when it completes.  Here's some C# pseudocode that demonstrates.

```
// we're in the UI thread here
PleaseWait = true; // indicate to the user we'll be back soon
var whatever = GetStuffFromTheUIThatWeNeedInTheOtherThreadLol();
Task.Run(() => 
{
    // here we're on a background thread
    var result = OurLongRunningOperation(whatever);
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        // we're back on the UI thread here
        UpdateUIWithResultsOfLongTimeOperationDerp(result);
        PleaseWait = false;
    }));
});
// snip
```